# Define Powershell function that takes a PSCredential object, but won't prompt if it's null?

Tags: powershell

I have a Powershell function that takes a PSCredential object. If the PSCredential is null, I want to handle that specially in the function myself. However, what ends up happening is I get a PSCredential prompt (the same prompt as when you run `Get-Credential`).

[image: PSCredential prompt example]

In my script below, I make the parameter required for the `Credential` parameter set, and I wanted to make it nullable with `[AllowNull()]`, but that didn't stop the prompt from appearing.

Here's my function:

```
<#
.description
Create a new Connection String Builder object
.parameter existingCSB
Use the passed CSB as the base, but allow it to be overridden.
.parameter property
Hashtable containing named properties for a connection string builder.
Will override values on -existingCSB.
.parameter credential
Use these credentials. Will override values on -existingCSB and any values
passed as -property.
NOTE: If this parameter is null, or if EITHER the username OR password in
the credential is an empty string, use a trusted connection aka 
integrated security instead
.parameter username
Use this username. Will override values on -existingCSB and any values
passed as -property
NOTE: If EITHER the username OR password is null or an empty string, use a
trusted connection / integrated security instead
.parameter password
Use this password. Can be a string or a SecureString object. Will override
values on -existingCSB and any values passed as -property
NOTE: If EITHER the username OR password is null or an empty string, use a
trusted connection / integrated security instead
#>
function New-DbConnectionStringBuilder {
    [cmdletbinding(DefaultParameterSetName="NoCredential")] param(
        [System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder] $existingCSB,

        [Hashtable] $property,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName="Credential")]
        [AllowNull()] [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential] $credential,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName="UserPass")]
        [AllowEmptyString()] [string] $username,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName="UserPass")]
        [AllowNull()] $password
    )
    $newDbCSB = New-Object System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder $true
    if ($existingCSB.Keys.Count -gt 0) {
        $existingCSB.Keys |% { $newDbCSB[$_] = [String]::Copy($existingCSB[$_]) }
    }
    if ($property.Keys.Count -gt 0) {
        $property.Keys |% { $newDbCSB[$_] = [String]::Copy($property[$_]) }
    }

    if ($PsCmdlet.ParameterSetName -notmatch "NoCredential") {
        if ($credential) {
            $username = $credential.UserName
            $password = $credential.Password
        }
        if ($password -and $password.GetType().FullName -eq "System.Security.SecureString") {
            $password = Decrypt-SecureString $password
        }

        if ($username -and $password) {
            $newDbCSB["Uid"] = $username
            $newDbCSB["Pwd"] = $password
            $newDbCSB.Remove("Trusted_Connection") | Out-Null
        }
        else {
            $newDbCSB["Uid"] = $null
            $newDbCSB["Pwd"] = $null
            $newDbCSB["Trusted_Connection"] = "yes"
        }
    }

    return $newDbCSB
}
```

Here's some code to call it:

```
$csb = New-DbConnectionStringBuilder -credential $null
Write-Host "UID: $($csb['Uid'])"
Write-Host "Trusted_Connection: $($csb['Trusted_Connection'])"
```

In case you're interested, the reason I'm doing this is for compatibility with existing code. We have some scripts that obtain credentials from encrypted files checked into Git. If a credential isn't present, the existing code will return $null as an indication that integrated security should be used instead.

The behavior I want, summarized, is: if no credentials are passed at all, do not add credential information to the CSB; if credentials are passed but $null, then use integrated security (aka a "trusted connection"); if credentials are passed and not null, then use them in the CSB.

Comment: You can add an [AllowNull] attribute to the parameter declaration to met PowerShell know that $Null is allowed as a value.

Comment: @oɔɯǝɹ I've done that - see my code. It isn't failing, as it would if I were passing $null to a required parameter that was not annotated with [AllowNull()]... but it's still giving me the PSCredential popup I screenshotted.

Comment: This may be a problem of using multiple parameter sets and specifying parameters from multiple sets?

Comment: You should accept whichever answer (including you own) that solved your question so this question will be marked as answered and closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing called a null-valued `PSCredential`-parameter. It will force you to input some type of credentials. The easiest solution is to check the input you want to pass to `-Credential` and replace it with `[pscredential]::Empty` if it's `$null`. Ex.

```
$creds = $null
if($creds -eq $null) { $creds = ([System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]::Empty) }
$csb = New-DbConnectionStringBuilder -credential $creds
```

Also, you can simplify the password part by using:

```
if ($credential) {
    $username = $credential.UserName
    $password = $credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password
}
```

Modified solution:

```
function New-DbConnectionStringBuilder {
    [cmdletbinding(DefaultParameterSetName="NoCredential")] param(
        [System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder] $existingCSB,

        [Hashtable] $property,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName="Credential")]
        [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential] $credential,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName="UserPass")]
        [string] $username,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName="UserPass")]
        $password
    )

    $newDbCSB = New-Object System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder $true
    if ($existingCSB.Keys.Count -gt 0) {
        $existingCSB.Keys |% { $newDbCSB[$_] = [String]::Copy($existingCSB[$_]) }
    }
    if ($property.Keys.Count -gt 0) {
        $property.Keys |% { $newDbCSB[$_] = [String]::Copy($property[$_]) }
    }

    if($PsCmdlet.ParameterSetName -ne "NoCredential") {

        if ($PsCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq "Credential" -and $credential -ne [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]::Empty) {
            $username = $credential.UserName.Split("\")[-1]
            $password = $credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password
        }

        if ($username -and $password) {
            $newDbCSB["Uid"] = $username
            $newDbCSB["Pwd"] = $password
            $newDbCSB.Remove("Trusted_Connection") | Out-Null
        }
        else {
            $newDbCSB["Uid"] = $null
            $newDbCSB["Pwd"] = $null
            $newDbCSB["Trusted_Connection"] = "yes"
        }

    }

    $newDbCSB
}
```

Demo:

```
Write-host
Write-host Null creds
Write-host
$creds = $null

if($creds -eq $null) { $creds = ([System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]::Empty) }
$csb = New-DbConnectionStringBuilder -credential $creds

Write-Host "UID: $($csb["Uid"])"
write-host "pass: $($csb["pwd"])"
Write-Host "Trusted_Connection: $($csb["Trusted_Connection"])"

Write-host
Write-host Creds
Write-host
$creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential "frode", (ConvertTo-SecureString -String "lol" -AsPlainText -Force)

if($creds -eq $null) { $creds = ([System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]::Empty) }
$csb = New-DbConnectionStringBuilder -credential $creds

Write-Host "UID: $($csb["Uid"])"
write-host "pass: $($csb["pwd"])"
Write-Host "Trusted_Connection: $($csb["Trusted_Connection"])"

Write-host
Write-host Username and password
Write-host
$csb = New-DbConnectionStringBuilder -username frode -password pass

Write-Host "UID: $($csb["Uid"])"
write-host "pass: $($csb["pwd"])"
Write-Host "Trusted_Connection: $($csb["Trusted_Connection"])"

Write-host
Write-host Nothing
Write-host
$csb = New-DbConnectionStringBuilder

Write-Host "UID: $($csb["Uid"])"
write-host "pass: $($csb["pwd"])"
Write-Host "Trusted_Connection: $($csb["Trusted_Connection"])"
```

Output:

```
Null creds

UID: 
pass: 
Trusted_Connection: yes

Creds

UID: frode
pass: lol
Trusted_Connection: 

Username and password

UID: frode
pass: pass
Trusted_Connection: 

Nothing

UID: 
pass: 
Trusted_Connection:
```

**EDIT**: Actually you can use a `[object]` parameter to accept the null-value credential and validate that it is a `PSCredential`-object inside your script, but you will lose the benefit of being prompted for password when writing `New-DbConnectionStringBuilder -Credential "frode"`.

I would prefer the solution above and validate the input (fix null-value) in your caller-script. That way the function would still be "best practice" and the user (you) will have the responsibility of cleaning/validating input like you're supposed to.

```
function New-DbConnectionStringBuilder {
    [cmdletbinding(DefaultParameterSetName="NoCredential")] param(
        [System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder] $existingCSB,

        [Hashtable] $property,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Credential")]
        [object] $credential,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName="UserPass")]
        [string] $username,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName="UserPass")]
        $password
    )

    #Validate credential-type
    if($credential -ne $null -and $credential -isnot [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]) { Write-Error -Message "credential parameter is not null or PSCredential" -Category InvalidArgument -ErrorAction Stop }

    $newDbCSB = New-Object System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder $true
    if ($existingCSB.Keys.Count -gt 0) {
        $existingCSB.Keys |% { $newDbCSB[$_] = [String]::Copy($existingCSB[$_]) }
    }
    if ($property.Keys.Count -gt 0) {
        $property.Keys |% { $newDbCSB[$_] = [String]::Copy($property[$_]) }
    }

    Write-Host ($credential -eq [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]::Empty)

    if($PsCmdlet.ParameterSetName -ne "NoCredential") {

        if ($credential -ne $null -and $credential -ne [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]::Empty) {
            $username = $credential.UserName.Split("\")[-1]
            $password = $credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password
        }

        if ($username -and $password) {
            $newDbCSB["Uid"] = $username
            $newDbCSB["Pwd"] = $password
            $newDbCSB.Remove("Trusted_Connection") | Out-Null
        }
        else {
            $newDbCSB["Uid"] = $null
            $newDbCSB["Pwd"] = $null
            $newDbCSB["Trusted_Connection"] = "yes"
        }

    }

    $newDbCSB
}

$creds = $null
$csb = New-DbConnectionStringBuilder -credential $creds

Write-Host "UID: $($csb["Uid"])"
write-host "pass: $($csb["pwd"])"
Write-Host "Trusted_Connection: $($csb["Trusted_Connection"])"
```

Comment: I accidently removed `NoCredential` support. Added now. :-)

Comment: Interesting. When you say "there's no such thing as a null PSCredential", is there some solution that works like what I am doing to allow for a null String object? A String object isn't directly nullable; that is, `[string]$null` is just an empty string, and in a type annotation, where otherwise you'd put `[AllowNull()]`, you have to put `[AllowEmptyString()]`. Is there an annotation that would understand that I wanted `-credential $null` to turn into `[PSCredential]::Empty` the same way that `[string]$null]` results in an empty string?

Comment: Not as far as I know. If credential was a string parameter, you would have a problem passing real credentials to it. As you've noticed, a pscredential-parameter will validate and require credentials while parameters are "processed" and not when they are actually used. At that stage in the execution we can only validate the value, not modify it. So the best solution would be to use validate and replace it with empty credentials in your script or create a simple wrapper-function that does it for you (and calls the real function)

Comment: Heh, that's pretty much the conclusion I came to in my own answer below

Comment: I can see that, but as mentioned I would not recommend that approach. You already have some kind of script that calls this function, so the best solution is to clean your input in the script which adds 1 line of logic. That way the function is still safe for interactive use (prompts for password), it's reusable and easy to use. You would never ask Microsoft to modify .NET Framework method to handle **your** bad input-data. :-)

Comment: I understand the appeal of requiring callers to fix inputs (and I could do the same for the -password parameter, instead of permitting it to be either a String or a SecureString). In my case, I call this function from several places, and all of them would have to "sanitize" the inputs. In a case where all callers would have to do the same work, putting that work in the called function makes a lot of sense to me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111146/discussion-between-micah-r-ledbetter-and-frode-f).

Comment: No need. In OOP (which PS is based on) it's important to split responsibility and fixing bad user input is not this methods job. I've given my recommendation, but in the end you decide what is best for your solution. Either way works and I've provided you with solutions for both ways of handling this. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get close enough to what I want by simply omitting the type annotation from the parameter. When I do that, Powershell doesn't start the PSCredential popup, and I can just handle everything inside my function.

Not the most elegant solution, perhaps, but it does work.

Here's my code:

```
<#
.description
Create a new Connection String Builder object
.parameter existingCSB
Use the passed CSB as the base, but allow it to be overridden.
.parameter property
Hashtable containing named properties for a connection string builder. Will override values on -existingCSB.
.parameter credential
Use these credentials. Will override values on -existingCSB and any values passed as -property.
NOTE: If this parameter is null, or if EITHER the username OR password in the credential is an empty string, use a trusted connection / integrated security instead
.parameter username
Use this username. Will override values on -existingCSB and any values passed as -property
NOTE: If EITHER the username OR password is null or an empty string, use a trusted connection / integrated security instead
.parameter password
Use this password. Can be a string or a SecureString object. Will override values on -existingCSB and any values passed as -property
NOTE: If EITHER the username OR password is null or an empty string, use a trusted connection / integrated security instead
#>
function New-DbConnectionStringBuilder {
    [cmdletbinding(DefaultParameterSetName="NoCredential")] param(
        [System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder] $existingCSB,

        [Hashtable] $property,

        # Do not give a type, so that this may be $null or a PSCredential object
        # NOTE that there is no such thing as a null PSCredential object - the closest thing is [PSCredential]::Empty
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName="Credential")]
        # [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]
        [AllowNull()] $credential,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName="UserPass")]
        [AllowEmptyString()] [string] $username,

        # Do not give a type, so that this might be a string or a SecureString
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName="UserPass")]
        [AllowNull()] $password
    )

    $newDbCSB = New-Object System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder $true
    if ($existingCSB.Keys.Count -gt 0) {
        $existingCSB.Keys |% { $newDbCSB[$_] = [String]::Copy($existingCSB[$_]) }
    }
    if ($property.Keys.Count -gt 0) {
        $property.Keys |% { $newDbCSB[$_] = [String]::Copy($property[$_]) }
    }

    if ($PsCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq "Credential") {
        if ($credential) {
            # Note that we assume this is a PSCredential object, but it could be anything with a string UserName property and a string or SecureString Password property
            $tmpUser = $credential.UserName
            $tmpPass = $credential.Password
        }
        else {
            $tmpUser = $tmpPass = $null
        }
    }
    elseif ($PsCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq "UserPass") {
        $tmpUser = $username
        $tmpPass = $password
    }

    if ($PsCmdlet.ParameterSetName -notmatch "NoCredential") {
        if ($tmpPass -and $tmpPass.GetType().FullName -eq "System.Security.SecureString") {
            $tmpPass = Decrypt-SecureString $tmpPass
        }

        if ($tmpUser -and $tmpPass) {
            $newDbCSB["Uid"] = $tmpUser
            $newDbCSB["Pwd"] = $tmpPass
            $newDbCSB.Remove("Trusted_Connection") | Out-Null
        }
        else {
            $newDbCSB["Uid"] = $null
            $newDbCSB["Pwd"] = $null
            $newDbCSB["Trusted_Connection"] = "yes"
        }
    }

    return $newDbCSB
}
```